# How to add a button once you click a button

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

OK i'm really new and i may just be doing something stupid but here is what i typed and i just want to know why once i hit the button the J Labels AL, BL, CL and the text fields A,B,C don't appear but the "pythag has been clicked" is still typed. (it works outside of the if loop but I don't know how to make it work in the if loop)

```js
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JFrameStuff extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new JFrameStuff().setVisible(true);
  
 }

 public  JFrameStuff() {
  super("Math");
  setSize(400, 300);
  setResizable(false);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  
  JButton bton1 = new JButton("Pythagorean Math");// 1

  JPanel pythag = new JPanel();

  bton1.addActionListener(this);
  add(bton1);
  add(pythag);


 

 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String name = e.getActionCommand();

  if (name.equals("Pythagorean Math")) {
   System.out.println("pythag has been clicked");
   JLabel AL = new JLabel("A");
   JLabel BL = new JLabel("B");
   JLabel CL = new JLabel("C");
   
   JTextField A = new JTextField(200);
   JTextField B = new JTextField(200);
   JTextField C = new JTextField(200);
    add(AL);
    add(A);
    add(BL);
    add(B);
    add(CL);
    add(C);
          }
 }
}
```

Comment: Try calling getContentPane().validate(); getContentPane().repaint(); after adding your components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must refresh the view. Use validate(); after adding the components.

Comment: trying that hold on ....yep im stupid ty ^-^ now secondary question how do I change the post to answered?
edit: nvm found it but i cant click it for another 6 min ty anyway